# Magento 2 - Switching currency only changing symbol on cart page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, multicurrency

I am using Magento 2.1.8, when we change currency fro INR to USD or USD to INR, it only changes symbol instead of complete calculation at Estimate Shipping and Tax box. See attached screenshot[image]

Comment: can we force shipping calculation when currency change on cart page?